# Qt send data from PC by serial port

Tags: qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I am trying to send data from PC to crossbow motes.The data format PC receives from the serial port is like:

> 7E 45 0 FF FF 0 0 12 0 89 0 5 0 0 27 B 0 0 27 AF 0 0 26 E7 0 0 27 BF 37 D4 7E

The Qt fun implementation of the send button is as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_sendData_clicked()
{
    QVector<quint8> senddata;
    quint8 *alldata=new quint8[8];
    int ij;
    alldata[0]=0x7e;
    alldata[1]=0x44;
    alldata[2]=0x00;
    alldata[3]=0x00;
    alldata[4]=0xff;
    alldata[5]=0xff;
    alldata[6]=0x00;
    alldata[7]=0x00;
    for (ij=0;ij<8;ij++)
        senddata.append(alldata[ij]);
     //senddata.append("7E 44 0F 00 FF FF 00 00");
    //QSerialPort *serial=new QSerialPort(ui->portNameComboBox->currentText());
    QString string=ui->SendMseLineEdit->text();
    string=string.simplified();
    quint8 sendlen=(quint8)(string.count(QRegExp(" "))+1);

//    if (sendlen==10)
//        sendlen=0x0a;
    senddata.append(sendlen);//payload
    senddata.append(0x00);
    senddata.append(0x89);
    QString tmp;
    quint8 *payload=new quint8[sendlen];
    for (ij=0;ij<sendlen;ij++)
    {
        tmp.append(string[2*ij]);
        tmp.append(string[2*ij+1]);
        payload[ij]=(quint8)tmp.toInt(0,16);//QString-int
        senddata.append(payload[ij]);
    }
    quint8 *dest=senddata.data();
    //qDebug()<<dest[0];
    quint16 sendcrc=calc(dest,1,sendlen+10);
    quint8  sendhigh=(quint8)(sendcrc>>8);
    quint8  sendlow =(quint8)(sendcrc&0xFF);
    senddata.append(sendlow);
    senddata.append(sendhigh);// crc
    senddata.append(0x7e);
    qDebug()<<senddata;
    int totalsize=senddata.size();
   QString sendstring;
//   // sendarray.resize(totalsize);
    for (ij=0;ij<totalsize;ij++)
    {
        if (senddata.at(ij)<=0x0f)
            sendstring.append(tr("0"));//
        sendstring.append(QString::number(senddata[ij],16));//QVcetor-QString
//        sendstring.append(tr(" "));

   }
   // qDebug()<<sendstring;

    qint64 testlen=0;
    QByteArray sendarray=sendstring.toLocal8Bit();//QString-QByteArray
    qDebug()<<sendarray;

    char *chardata=new char[sendarray.size()];//QByteArray-char
    strcpy(chardata,sendarray.data());
    qDebug()<<sendarray.size();
    for (ij=0;ij<sendarray.size();ij++)
    {
        if (ij%2==0)
    testlen=testlen+serial->write(chardata+ij,1);

    }
     qDebug()<<testlen;

}
/****************CRC************************/
 quint16 MainWindow::calcByte(int crc,int b)
{
    crc=crc^(int) b<<8;
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if ((crc &0x8000)==0x8000)
            crc=crc<<1^0x1021;
        else
            crc=crc<<1;
    }
    return crc & 0xffff;
 }

 quint16 MainWindow::calc(quint8 *packet, int index, int count)
{
    quint16 crc=0;
    //int i;
    while(count>0){
        crc =calcByte(crc,packet[index++]);
        count--;
    }
    return crc;
}


void MainWindow::on_openserial_clicked()
{
    QPainterPath linepath;
    paintwiget=new paint(linepath,ui->scrollArea);
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(paintwiget);
    paintwiget->show();
    if (serial->isOpen())
    {
        QMessageBox::about(this,tr("info"),tr("Serial port is already open"));
    return;
    }
```

The problem is that when the send button is pressed,the content sent is :

> 7e440000ffff000002008901009f1a7e

and it is the exact transmission format I want (if I have not made a mistake in the correct serial data format).But the mote didn't receive the data (when data arrives, the led may toggle).
    I do not know if it is okay to ask question related with serial port here.But it is really appreciated if the question is to be answered. Thank the responders in advance.

Comment: I don't see any serial communication in your code? Just doing stuff with strings and arrays (and leaking memory all over the place)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a part of my whole serial communication process.Every time send button is pressed, this function is supposed to be called and a series of data with correct format is transmited from PC serial port to node. I am not familiar with object oriented coding,so cannot identify occurence of memory leaking.

Comment: Leak: Every time a `new` isn't matched by a corresponding `delete`. Show the code where you actually send the data.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld: The part that sends data was actually marked as comments before.Now the code is renewed.Just for your reference please.

Comment: Your code is inclomplete. You never opened a serial here. See usage here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort. Also try to removed all that string and array stuff from the example code. Why don't you just create a QByteArray whith your data ?

Comment: Thank you @Frank Osterfeld, that is not the problem. My serial port is opened already when I click the "send" button.Part of the send function is shown above .The code region is rewritten again.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue in the meantime?